# What is "JIT must be enabled" error while using MATLAB?

Tags: windows, matlab, error-handling

I am trying to execute a piece of code which takes `fast curvelet transform` using 32-bit MATLAB and toolbox in [this](http://jstarck.cosmostat.org/cur3d/) website. When I execute the line reconstructing signal from its curvelet coefficients, it shows an error:

[image: MATLAB error message]

the line making this error has a break point in the image above. Any of the three choices in this error message results in termination of whole MATLAB program.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This is not a MATLAB error message, but a default Windows one. See [Just-In-Time Debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information. Note that this will (probably) not be useful for you to solve the problem.

Comment: @m7913d Thank you for answering. what do you mean of not being useful? I want to solve this problem, whether it is a windows problem or MATLAB. Thank you for the link, I will check it.

Comment: You can read the link and decide yourself, but note that it probably involves compiling the toolbox (sapdev?) yourself to enable to JIT option.

Comment: @m7913d Thank you for your response. As I read the link, it will help me to debug the toolbox and recompile it. I used this toolbox without error before but there is now a burden which does not relate to this error I wrote. Thanks again.

Comment: When a C/C++/Fortran code that is called via MATLAB fails, MATLAB crashes with a generic error. This could be a out of memory, a segmentation fault, or some other similar error but MATLAB handles it very poorly and just "dies". So the only thing you know is that there is an unknown error in the compiled code

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thanks Ander, I think I should leave it as is...